# Kettle job deployment in production

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I developed a simple job that loads data from multiple excel file to a mysql database in pentaho Kettle, I'm using Kitchen.bat from cmd line to run the job. If i need to move the job to other production serverthe application size is more than a GB, is there any way i could deploy the job without moving all the libraries to the production server.

Comment: you have to keep your job somewhere in production server and by making it parameterized you can execute it without doing any changes in existing job.

Comment: The job has to be on a production server. It doesn't need to be the same as the pentaho server, but if you execute the job on your development machine that basically just turns your development machine into a production machine, which is never advised.